# Can I Programmatically Select Text in UITextView?

Tags: iphone, select, text, uitextview, highlight

I want to select Text on UITextView, similar to the default "Select" and "Select All" pop options we see when we tap.  I want to the user the ability to do that from my custom menu.  I played with selectedRange but that doesnt seem to do the trick.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code where you've tried to use `selectedRange`? That sounds like the right approach; it's possible you're giving it an invalid range or something.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I'm able to get the correct range for the text I'd like to select (the UITextView scrolls to the correct position) but there is no "highlight" of the text in the range nor an insertion point.  I'm wondering if I need to send a message to the UITextView to "activate" or something first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `selectedRange` property should do it but, as mentioned in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006898-CH3-SW10), only in iPhone OS 3.0 and later.  In 2.2 and earlier, the `selectedRange` property is actually an insertion point.

Comment: Note the function to create an `NSRange` is `NSMakeRange()` not `NSRangeMake()` as you might expect.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the accepted answer, the `selectedRange` property is the thing you need, but beware that if you are using the `-textViewDidBeginEditing:` delegate method you might need to defer one run loop in order to win out over the user generated "insertion" action:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    // Look for the default message and highlight it if present
    NSRange defaultMsgRange = [textView.text rangeOfString:NSLocalizedString(@"TEXTFIELD_DEFAULT_MESSAGE", nil) options:NSAnchoredSearch];

    BOOL isDefaultMsg = !(defaultMsgRange.location == NSNotFound && defaultMsgRange.length == 0);
    if (isDefaultMsg) {

        // Need to delay this by one run loop otherwise the insertion wins
        [self performBlock:^(id sender) {  // (BlocksKit - use GCD otherwise)

            textView.selectedRange = defaultMsgRange;

        } afterDelay:0.0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just do:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView.selectAll(textView)
}
```

which seems to work pretty well, and adds a couple nice features IMO, like if you tap on the existing text, it selects it all; if you tap at the beginning or end of the text, it puts the cursor there without selecting all (which kinda seems natural).