# Selecting all text in a UITextView on focus only after UIAlertView

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitextview

I have a tableView that contains a few UITextView controls. When the user taps on one of these the text inside should be selected so that any keyboard input immediately replaces the original content.

I cannot get the text inside a UITextView selected using this code:

```
txtQuantity.SelectAll (new NSObject(NSObjectFlag.Empty));
```

as this code only shows the menu "Select | Select All' without the text being actually selected.

Has someone gotten this to work?

EDIT:
The code below select the text inside the txtQuantity control, BUT ONLY IF the UIAlert is show first! Why is this?

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            txtQuantity.TouchDown += txtQuantityHandleTouchDown;

            txtQuantity.EditingDidBegin += delegate {

                txtQuantity.ExclusiveTouch=true;
                UIAlertView uv = new UIAlertView("","OK",null,"OK",null);
                uv.Show ();
            };

        }

        void txtQuantityHandleTouchDown (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtQuantity.SelectAll (this);
            txtQuantity.Selected = true;

        }
```

If all code within the txtQuality.EditingBegin delegate is commented out, the HandleTouchDown event does not fire.

Comment: Can you use the selectedRange property?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634425/can-i-programmatically-select-text-in-uitextview

Comment: Sadly selectedRange is not an option for me: MonoTouch limitation?
I've tried 'txtQuantity.SetMarkedText (txtQuantity.Text, new NSRange(0, txtQuantity.Text.Length));' but it also does nothing.

Comment: Looks like there may be a missing binding in Monotouch.  I am thinking you can PInvoke into ObjectiveC to accomplish the task, but that is a pain.  I hope my answer below is what you really need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that this is what you are going for but I put together a quick sample.

The problem I was having is with calling SelectAll in EditingDidBegin. I had to make a call to BeginInvokeOnMainThread to get the select to work.  I am not sure if it is a problem with the event not happening on the main thread or you simply need to make an async call on the main thread.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace SelectText
{
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        // class-level declarations
        UIWindow window;

        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            // create a new window instance based on the screen size
            window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            window.RootViewController = new MyTableViewController ();

            // make the window visible
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

            return true;
        }
    }

    public class MyTableViewController : UITableViewController
    {
        public override void LoadView ()
        {
            base.LoadView ();
            this.TableView.DataSource = new TableViewDataSource ();
        }
        private class TableViewDataSource : UITableViewDataSource
        {
            private class EditCell : UITableViewCell
            {
                UITextField _field;

                public EditCell () : base (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, "mycell")
                {
                    _field = new UITextField (this.Bounds);
                    _field.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
                    _field.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
                    _field.ShouldReturn = delegate {
                        _field.ResignFirstResponder ();

                        return true;
                    };

                    _field.EditingDidBegin += delegate {
                        this.BeginInvokeOnMainThread ( delegate {
                            _field.SelectAll (this);
                        });
                    };

                    _field.Text = "Some Text";
                    this.Add (_field);
                }

                public override void LayoutSubviews ()
                {
                    base.LayoutSubviews ();
                    _field.Frame = this.Bounds;
                }


            }

            #region implemented abstract members of UITableViewDataSource           
            public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableView, int section)
            {
                return 2;
            }           

            public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell ("mycell");

                if (cell == null)
                {
                    cell = new EditCell ();
                }

                cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;

                return cell;
            }           
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've used this part of your suggestion:  
 _field.ShouldReturn = delegate {
                        _field.ResignFirstResponder ();

                        return true;
                    };

                    _field.EditingDidBegin += delegate {
                        this.BeginInvokeOnMainThread ( delegate {
                            _field.SelectAll (this);
                        });
                    };    but no success.

Comment: I am guessing that it is how that you are adding the textfiled to the cell. I have seen problems with child views added to cells where they do not behave correctly. For example, an UIImageView added to a cell may not update when you assign a new image. The fix to that particular problem is to add the Imageview to a dummy view and add that to the the cell. Without seeing your code, I have no other suggestion. The sample I have provided does show that SelectAll can work. Happy hunting

Comment: 've added an AlertView inside the event's delegate, and after I clicked on the resulting msgbox the text is indeed selected, BUT if if I don't show the UIAlertView, SelecTAll() doesn't work. See My Edit for clarification. I would love to mark your answer as correct soon! 
The textField was added using the storyboard in xcode, so not during runtime.

Comment: Thanks! what finally got it working was your description above: "I had to make a call to BeginInvokeOnMainThread to get the select to work".